# How to Get Data from MySQL based on Selected Value in Spinner Android Dynamically

Tags: android, mysql, spinner

I'm trying to make an Android app where when user select static value I set from Spinner it will display certain amount of data from MySQL that match the selected value in tableView.
below is the static values I set:

```
<string-array name="hari">
    <item>Senin</item>
    <item>Selasa</item>
    <item>Rabu</item>
    <item>Kamis</item>
    <item>Jumat</item>
</string-array>
```

for example when user select "Senin" from Spinner, the app then will show certain amount of data from MySQL that has word "Senin".
I want to show all the data that has word "Senin" in tableView in app.

[image: Certain Amount of Data that Match The Selected Value]

I tried using Volley to load all data from MySQL to Spinner but what I get is all data without being filtered into 5 values ("Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat").

Answer (score 0):

It's all about select query depend on what database you use,
where selected item from spinner should be pass to where clause to find what you looking for.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE jadwal_hari=?";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { ... });
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("..."));
}
c.close();
```

Comment: thanks for answering @MCZ. but in this app I'm using PHP as server side.. so I need to pass the selected value to PHP first then PHP will pass it back to my app.

Comment: so what's a deal ? you pass data by soap or any different method to server side and then query your statement